# Defined increase of a value in a counter

Tags: java, counter

I am currently in an introduction to Java class and I am having an issue with the counter.  The only thing that is not working as intended is the increment in which the value must go up. Here is the objective that I am trying to complete:

> The application should also display a table of potential total annual compensation that the salesperson could have earned, in $5000 increments above the salesperson’s annual sales, until it reaches 50% above the salesperson’s annual sales.

I am unable make the output go up by increments of $5000 after the initial output. Here is the code that I am using:

```
count = annualSales + 5000;
    count2 = count * .03 * 1.25;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(count + " | " + count2 );

        }
```

And this is the output that I am recieving:

```
What was the total of your annual sales this year?:
100000
Your annual sales where: $100000.0
Your annual salary was: $45000.0
Your total commission was: $3750.0
Your total compensation was: $48750.0
$105000.0 | $3937.5
$105000.0 | $3937.5
$105000.0 | $3937.5 And so on...
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're incrementing `i`, but you're printing `count` and `count1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the `count` and `count2` inside the loop.  This way it'll increment.

```
count = annualSales;//initial value
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    count = count + 5000;//increment it by 5000 every iteration
    count2 = count * .03 * 1.25;//recalcualte count2
    System.out.println(count + " | " + count2 );
}
```

Comment: Outstanding, thank you very much. Works like a charm!

Comment: @TravisDykhoff No problem! If you found this answer correct, mark it so  :)

Comment: Yeah, I just had to wait the allotted time before I could.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code, you never actually use the `i` variable and are using the `count2` and `count` variables. You will need to change either one to `i`.

```
count = annualSales + 5000;
count2 = count * .03 * 1.25;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    System.out.println(count + " | " + count2 );

}
```

You may have intended to do the calculations inside the loop, using the `i` variable.

Comment: If you want to increment `count` by 5000, you can set it to `annualSales + 5000 * i` for example.

Comment: @Hassan or just `count += 5000`

Comment: Agreed. I was just assuming he wants to use `i` for something else, but that's probably a bad assumption.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the code that @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc gave and it worked perfectly.